# control wordlist for gesture typing IME

Tags: android, ime, android-input-method

Is there a way/API to control the wordlist for the gesture typing IME? Mainly interested in the stock one that came with JellyBean, but compatibility with Touchpal, Swype, .. would also be nice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You won't get compatibility with Swype, and probably not any of the other big keyboards outside the default-  the format of the wordlist is part of the app, and stores information like usage frequency for better predictions.

New as of 4.0 Android added the SpellCheckerService, which handles single tap editing for the default keyboard.  If you implemented your own it may work for the default keyboard.  Its less likely to work for others, but they could pull from it as a source.  I don't know of anyone who's actually implemented one though, so expect surprises.